# Why perform bitwise operations here? (SPI FRAM read method)

Tags: c++

See: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_FRAM_SPI/blob/master/Adafruit_FRAM_SPI.cpp
The following method reads and converts the input to 8 bit. I have several questions concerning its function.

Using addr = 0xFFFF as an example, the method converts the variable to 0xFF. I understand that bits are removed from the end, but surely 65535 != 255. Perhaps relatively, to their max size, but how is this a useful conversion? I might be missing something about bitwise here..

```
uint8_t Adafruit_FRAM_SPI::read8 (uint16_t addr)
{
 digitalWrite(_cs, LOW);
 SPItransfer(OPCODE_READ); //read memory from fram array (2-byte)
 SPItransfer((uint8_t)(addr >> 8));
 SPItransfer((uint8_t)(addr & 0xFF));
 uint8_t x = SPItransfer(0);
 digitalWrite(_cs, HIGH);
 return x;
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, the casting is to keep sign extension from occurring.

The masking I understand in theory, but do not at all understand its application here.

Finally, it always returns the same value x = 0, why?

I also see there's a write method but no read method. Only read8. Reasoning?

Comment: Think about what happens to the numbers and then plug those into 4 SPI transfers and think about what actually then happens on the SPI bus.

Comment: The code above first send the highest 8 bits of the address (`addr>>8`), and then the lowest 8 bits. Not sure why they do both masking  and casting. After that it sends 8 zero bits. During the sending of those bits the FRAM send the value in the address to the arduinos MISO pin. The 8-bit value is stored in the `x variable. Note that SPI is bi-directional, and you can send and receive data at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume `addr` is `0xbeef`. Then, if we break down each operation:

```
expression             │ value
───────────────────────┼───────
addr                   │ 0xbeef
addr >> 8              │ 0x00be
(uint8_t)(addr >> 8)   │   0xbe
addr & 0xFF            │ 0x00ef
(uint8_t)(addr & 0xFF) │   0xef
```

So this is essentially breaking down the address into two 8-bit chunks,
and transmitting those chunks individually. It's done like this because
SPI only transmits bytes.

> the casting is to keep sign extension from occurring.

Non, sign extension cannot occur, since `addr` is an unsigned number.
The casting really serves no useful purpose, other than documenting the
code. It would be done implicitly simply because `SPItransfer()` takes
an `uint8_t` argument. The casting *could* be useful if `SPItransfer()`
was overloaded with a 16-bit version.

> Finally, it always returns the same value x = 0, why?

No, it returns whatever the call to `SPItransfer(0);` returns, i.e. the
data sent by the FRAM module.